Is it possible to remove an element from y HashMap without cloning the key
when writing various algorithms (in the scope of advent of code) I needed to "pop" any key value pair from a HashMap.
Basically this could be done like that:
let mut hash_map = HashMap::from([
    ("one".to_owned(), 1),
    ("two".to_owned(), 2),
    ("three".to_owned(), 3),
]);

let key = hash_map.keys().next().unwrap();
hash_map.remove(key);

But of course it doesn't work since the key is a reference into the HashSet therefore it can't be mutated and it can be achieved by copying the key via clone() or to_owned() :
  let mut hash_map = HashMap::from([
    ("one".to_owned(), 1),
    ("two".to_owned(), 2),
    ("three".to_owned(), 3),
]);

let key = hash_map.keys().next().unwrap().to_owned();
hash_map.remove(&key);

I'm rather new to rust and my question now is, is there something I am missing and can an entry be removed without cloning the key ?
Or must it be cloned in this use case ? (IMHO that would be a little disappointing, since copying strings isn't that cheap)

An alternative design might have you store the strings somewhere else (in a Vec, say) and then use references to them as keys in the HashMap.

Yes, there is a way to remove entries without cloning the key. But it only works if you don't mess with the borrow checker. Your example won't compile for exactly the reason you mention in your post. You're holding a reference to the map and try to mutate it at the same time. That is not allowed.
For all other scenarios, you can use any type T when the actual key implements Borrow<T>. For example, you can remove a key of type String by using &str, because String satisfies Borrow<str>.
let mut map = HashMap::new();
map.insert("one".to_owned(), 1);
map.remove("one"); 

Note that if you first search for a key and then want to remove that key, you would normally use entry and remove_entry. This is the equivalent of removing a key by using a reference to that key. However, to get an entry, you need a copy of the key. So this won't solve your problem either.

Removing an entry from a HashMap without cloning the key can be challenging due to the borrowing rules. The problem arises because when you call hash_map.keys(), it generates an iterator that borrows the keys. This means you cannot mutate the HashMap while a reference to one of its keys is still active.
Why Cloning is Necessary in This Approach
When you use hash_map.keys().next(), you obtain a reference to the key, but you cannot remove an entry from the HashMap while holding that reference. To work around this restriction, you must clone the key using to_owned(), which creates a separate copy of the key. While this method works, it can be inefficient, especially if the keys are large or expensive to clone, such as strings.

This is a small test I ran, I tried to use std::mem::replace to replace the keys in the HashMap and basically rendering them unusable but rust doesn't allow that to happen, rightfully so. HashMaps aren't designed to be messed with directly.
This is a little benchmark I wrote to see which method is fastest:
use std::{collections::HashMap, time::Instant};

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<i32, i32> = HashMap::new();
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let init_size = 1_000_000;
    let remove_size = 100_000;
    
    let start = Instant::now();

    for _ in 0..init_size {
        while let Some(_) = map.insert(rng.gen(), rng.gen()) {} //This is to make sure there are no accidental duplicates, causing the total number to be lower.
    }

    let end = Instant::now();
    println!("Init time -> {:?}", end - start);

    //#############################################
    let mut map_clone = map.clone();

    let start = Instant::now();

    for _ in 0..remove_size {
        let key = map_clone.keys().next().unwrap().clone();
        map_clone.remove(&key);
    }

    let end = Instant::now();
    println!("Original method -> {:?}", end - start);
    
    //#############################################
    let mut map_clone = map.clone();

    let start = Instant::now();

    let mut _keys = Vec::new();
    _keys = map_clone.keys().copied().collect();
    for i in 0..remove_size {
        map_clone.remove(&_keys[i]);
    }

    let end = Instant::now();
    println!("Purge method -> {:?}", end - start);

    //#############################################
    let map_clone = map.clone();

    let start = Instant::now();

    let mut map_iter = map_clone.into_iter();

    for _ in 0..remove_size {
        map_iter.next();
    }

    let _map_clone: HashMap<i32, i32> = map_iter.collect();

    let end = Instant::now();
    println!("into_iter() method -> {:?}", end - start);
}

And this is the result for 1,000,000 total and 100,000 removals:
Init time -> 66.3639ms
Original method -> 271.0964ms
Purge method -> 5.3426ms
into_iter() method -> 27.6838ms

Now for 1,000,000 total and 500,000 removals:
Init time -> 53.3091ms
Original method -> 5.7346098s
Purge method -> 9.5229ms
into_iter() method -> 13.6201ms

And now for full removal of 1,000,000 pairs:
Init time -> 69.54ms
Original method -> 23.1595835s
Purge method -> 18.0148ms
into_iter() method -> 2.9514ms

Purge method is the best overall with the most consistent results, the into_iter() method is incredibly fast when you remove most of the components, because it doesn't have to collect them all back into a HashMap and the original naive method is the worst overall because it has to clone and remove one by one, and each time it has to convert the whole HashMap into an iter over Keys.
I have not averaged these results out, but they are generally around the same ballpark.
Hope this was interesting to you as much as it was to me.
P.S. If you really need to go through your HashMap and remove stuff the iterator method is truly the best. If you would like more flexibility and the possibility of going back over your key-value pairs multiple times before you remove them then the Vec method is best.

Yes, it is possible, if you don't mind getting your hands dirty with unsafe
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut hash_map = HashMap::from([
        ("one".to_owned(), 1),
        ("two".to_owned(), 2),
        ("three".to_owned(), 3),
    ]);

    let key = hash_map.keys().next().unwrap();
    let key = key as *const String;
    hash_map.remove(unsafe { &*key });
}

SAFETY: this unsafe usage is justified and safe, as remove only needs a reference to key to compute the hash, and then it proceeds with dropping the key (using the computed hash), returning the value. As we are not using raw pointer after remove is invoked, we are not creating a dangling pointer.

You can use drain() or else into_iter() without being cloned to access and remove elements. You can use this approach only if the ownership is not necessary of HashMap.
Refer to the code below for reference:
let mut hash_map = HashMap::from([
    ("one".to_owned(), 1),
    ("two".to_owned(), 2),
    ("three".to_owned(), 3),
]);

if let Some((key, value)) = hash_map.drain().next() {
    println!("Removed: {} -> {}", key, value);
}


Unfortunately this doesn't work, because drain will empty the whole HashMap, even if just one item of the Iterator is consumed.
